# Get hash of apk

Tags: android

I'd like my app to compute and show a hash of the app's apk file.  It's easily done in Java, but how do I do it for an apk?

The problem is to get a path to the app's apk. In Java

URL url = AutoCheck.class.getResource("Main.class") ;

will find the needed url.

Comment: Do you have the path of the apk file?

Comment: No, that's the problem.  Can an app find the path to the app's apk file and then read it?

Answer (score 0):

I get the hash code with this code

```
private void getHash(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(YourPackageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("keyhash: " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot obtain keyhash, " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you need though

Comment: That would hash the signature, not the apk file.